# Dynamic Content w/ geolocation in WP?

Tags: url-rewriting, content, conditional-content, geo-data

I'm really just looking for ideas and guidance while foraging for memory processing in the WordPress CMS Divi Structure.

My company is in need of a good ContentPlaceholder solution.  True to the MVC thinking we need to minimize the creation of redundant resources and yet create a national website that serves the regional concerns of different states.  We are thinking of using geolocation (Google reverse lookup) but it has to allow standard users to add/manage the state dependant content blocks in WP.

CodeCanyon has a user role content placeholder plugin  https://codecanyon.net/item/wordpress-content-placeholders/9259679

There is a service like https://geolify.com/

There is alot of discussion out there on using .htaccess URL rewriting or RewriteCondition.
Perhaps something like URL.com/page?state_=TX

Maybe a custom PHP function could just pull the URL state value but I need to dig on PHP functionality within WP (with or without a custom plugin).

```
get_header();

get_footer();



> <?php $matches = Array();
> preg_match("/^\/questions/([0-9]+)\/([^\/]+)$/",
> $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $matches);
> 
> $db = new Database(); $seo_title = $db->getTitleById( $matches[1] );
> if( $seo_title != $matches[2] ) {   header( "Location:
> /questions/{$matches[1]}/{$seo_title}", TRUE, 301 );   exit(); } else
> {   display_the_page(); }
```

Another example:

> RewriteEngine on RewriteCond %{ENV:GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE} ^(US|CA)$
>   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/USA/$1 [L]

Or this example:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20994880/ip-geo-location-with-mod-rewrite-php

Answer (score 0):

Think I found my own answer, at least for now
A WP Plugin!
https://geotargetingwp.com/

Also we can look up more info regarding
Maxmind or Ip2Location databases

Making our own plugin doesn't work for part time I'm already working on one!